# key attribute OGNL issue in Struts2

Tags: struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I have been working with `Struts2` for a long time.

When I use `<s:textfield label="Product Id" key="%{productId}"/>` or `<s:textfield label="Product Id" key="[0].productId"/>` it is not working.
i.e. If I use first tag with key attribute pointing to OGNL expression `%{productId}` then the resulted `html` `input tag's` name attribute is coming as empty.i.e. `<input type="text" name="" value="" id="Product_Save_"/>`. If I use `<s:textfield label="Product Id" key="[0].productId"/>` tag then the resulted `html input tag` is `<input type="text" name="[0].productId" value="" id="Product_Save__0__productId"/>`.

In the both the cases Struts is not able to populate my request parameter into my model object which is product class which is as below:

```
public class Product{

private String productId;
private String productName;
private int price;
private ProductOwner productOwner;

public Product() {}

public Product(String productId, String productName, int price) {
    this.productId = productId;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.price = price;
}

public void setProductOwner(ProductOwner productOwner) {

    this.productOwner = productOwner;
}

public ProductOwner getProductOwner() {
    return productOwner;
}

public String getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(String productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

}
```

If I use `<s:textfield label="Product Id" key="productId"/>` then Struts is able to populate the `productId` into `Product` class `productId`.

But when I use `<s:property value="%{[0].productId}"/>` it is working properly.

Now my question is why I can not use full OGNL expressions like `%{[0].productId}`, But in `<s:property />` tag Why I can use full OGNL expressions like `%{[0].productId}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key="%{productId}` doesn't work because by using `%{}` you are forcing expression evaluation and you don't have value in `productId` so `name` attribute is empty.

The `key="[0].productId"` is a correct expression and normally would work in OGNL, but because it has certain security risks it is not allowed to use this expression to set values in Struts2. Of course it is allowed to get values by this expression so `<s:property value="[0].productId"/>` works.

Comment: I understood something from your answer. But if you ca elaborate that would be great help to me.

Comment: @Jagadeesh: Elaborate on what exactly? What are you not understanding?

Comment: if key="%{productId} and if I have productId then what happens? If key="[0].productId" then I am getting name attribute as "[0].productId" why it is like that?

Comment: @Jagadeesh: The value of `productId` will be put in the resulting html.

Comment: The value of productId will be put in the resulting html As name attribute or value attribute?

Comment: `key` is `name`, `value` and `label`.

Comment: @Jagadeesh: Have you understood?

Comment: If key="[0].productId" then I am getting name attribute as "[0].productId" why it is like that?

Comment: @Jagadeesh: Because it is a string it won't be evaluated in the `name` attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89353/discussion-between-jagadeesh-and-aleksandr-m).